# How to set the package/Theme for installation of magento

Tags: magento, themes, package, config

I have to extend the installation process of magento ... 
my first problem is how do I say magento to take the layoutfiles in app/design/install/default/myTheme? 
Is there a xml snippet to set the install theme / package in the config.xml of my extension?
something like this:

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <install>
        <design>
            <package>
                <name>default</name>
            </package>
            <theme>
                <default>ironshark</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </install>
    <!-- ... -->
<config>
```

Comment: The design is hard-coded to install area's default/default theme in `Mage_Install_Controller_Action::_construct()`; modifying it thereafter should yield the results you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but if I change the package / theme in this file and var_dump the following in my rewritten block  var_dump(Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(), Mage::getDesign()->getTheme()); there is still the default / default

Answer (score 0):

I have only one idea but where should start this snippet in setup I don't know.
So, you can change default setting in `core_config_data` table

```
$changeData = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();
$changeData->saveConfig('design/package/name', "myTheme", 'default', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Navigate to System >Configuration > General (Left Menu) >Design.**

There you have option to enter the package name and theme name. No need to change any bit of code. Magento will do the override.

Please read the following to know more about the magento theme selection.

**The template system in magento consists of**

•   XML layout configuration

•   PHP template files

•   PHP block classes

1. All layout XML files will be found in the app/design/frontend///layout folder.
2. All template files will be in the .phtml files found in various folders under the app/design/frontend///template folder.
3. All blocks will be in the app/code////Block folder.

You may not find all the layout/template files in same theme(alex). For example, Magento will check the following folders, in order, for a file named catalog.xml:

```
app/design/frontend/package/alex/layout/
app/design/frontend/package/default/layout/
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/
```